# Invoking @POST in jax-rs Endpoint

Tags: java, post, jax-rs, endpoints

I have an jax-rs endpoint as below. I need to post a message to a web page through this endpoint. When I execute the endpoint using a client the method with @GET executes. But the method with @POST does not execute. I need to know when will be the @POST method will execute. What should I do to invoke the @POST method.

```
 @GET
@Path("/")
@Produces("text/plain")

    public boolean getLoginStatus(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
return true;
}

 @POST
@Path("/")
public boolean helloPost() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's up to the client what kind of request it issues.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods.  If your client is a browser, it will probably use GET unless you are entering data into a form; I don't think there's any way to control that.  There are tools like Postman that will let you decide what request you want to try.

Comment: hi ajb thanks for the response. Actually my client is posting message to the endpoint using postMessage. When I'm posting a message to the endpoint, the method with @post annotation should be invoked. isn't it? But it is not invoking :(  postMessage(message,'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/session');

Comment: But is it using POST?

Comment: That is what i need to know actually. I should get the response from the endpoint and show from an iFrame which includes the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke a HTTP POST request from your client - be it a programmatic one (e.g. JAX-RS 2.0 client API), a browser or tools like curl etc. I would strongly suggest using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) client as a chrome browser extension to execute a POST request and test out your REST service